# find sum for one element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a `csv` with 9 columns and 1.5 million rows. The question asks us to compute the spending for each account. There are 7700 account numbers that I was able to extract. Here is an sample from the file since someone asked (it is a link since i don't have enough clout on here to post photos apparently):

[sample of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWPSV.png)

I'm especially confused given that you need to add the extra step of multiplying quantity and price since the transactions in the table are for individual items.

Oh, and we are not allowed to use `pandas`. And all of this is `string` data.

I have not tried much because I'm pretty stumped beyond simply getting the list of all of the account ids. Even that was a challenge for me, so any help is appreciated. Below is simply the code I used to get the list of IDs, and I'm pretty sure I wasn't even supposed to use import `csv` for that but oh well.

```
import csv

f_file = open ('myfile.csv')
csv_f_file = csv.reader(f_file)

account_id = []
for row in csv_f_file:
    account_id.append(row[4])

account_id = set(account_id)
account_id_list = list(account_id)

print(customer_id_list)
```

The result should look like this (but imagine it 7000 times):

```
account:  SID600   
spending: 87.500
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!!

Comment: how does the data look in the very large file, can you share a small part from it

Comment: @Sam, does your csv use a header?

Comment: @anfreihongrari yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv


with open ('myfile.csv') as f:
    csv_f_file = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(csv_f_file)
    res = {}
    for row in data:
        res[row[3]] = res.get(row[3], 0.0)
        res[row[3]] += float(row[4]) * float(row[5])
    print(res)
```

Comment: This didn't work, it gave me 0.0 for the first id. the first lines of output appears like this : {'CSYSTEMID': 0.0, 'C0044101043442': 0.0, 'C0044101011944': 0.0, 'C0044101046706': 0.0, 'C0044101004484': 1.3, 'C0044101047453': 0.0}. It says in the instructions that the first one should come out to 84000000. This was helpful though, thank you!!

Comment: Can you try now? I made a silly mistake updated the answer

Comment: it is giving me larger values now but still not the ones that are supposedly correct. here is the result: {'CSYSTEMID': 137661.44900002424, 'C0044101043442': 97.71000000000001, 'C0044101011944': 13.588999999999997, 'C0044101046706': 1.79, 'C0044101004484': 55.78999999999998}. This question is a real pain, I apologize.

Comment: If you can share some sample data for it then I can verify it.

Comment: okay, i just added a screencap from the file we were given to my question

Answer (score 0):

You could make it readable by using `DictReader` and `DictWriter`, but it's mandatory that you have the CSV with a header. Also you could save the results in another CSV for persistence.

Since in your input there may be a different product per entry for the same account (for example for `SID600` there could be entries for `chair`, `table` and some other `table`, with different prices and quantities), there is a need to gather all the spendings in lists for each account and then sum them to a total.

Sample CSV input:

```
date,trans,item,account,quantity,price
0409,h65009,chair,SID600,12.5,7
0409,h65009,table,SID600,40,2
0409,h65009,table,SID600,22,10
0409,h65009,chair,SID601,30,11
0409,h65009,table,SID601,30,11
0409,h65009,table,SID602,4,9
```

The code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

inpf = open("accounts.csv", "r")
outpf = open("accounts_spending.csv", "w")

incsv = csv.DictReader(inpf)
outcsv = csv.DictWriter(outpf, fieldnames=['account', 'spending'])

outcsv.writeheader()

spending = defaultdict(list)

# calculate spendings for all entries
for row in incsv:
    spending[row["account"]].append(float(row["quantity"]) * float(row["price"]))

# sum the spendings for all accounts
for account in spending:
    spending[account] = sum(spending[account])

# output the spending to a CSV
for account, total_spending in spending.items():
    outcsv.writerow({
        "account": account,
        "spending": total_spending
    })

inpf.close()
outpf.close()
```

for whose output will be:

```
account,spending
SID600,387.5
SID601,660.0
SID602,36.0
```

Comment: I think his `csv` file only has 2 columns with 6 rows.

Comment: @Yusufsn what makes you think that?

Comment: Read his first sentence. "There is a csv with 6 rows:..."

Comment: @Yusufsn `csv with 6 rows: date, transaction #, item, account, quantity, and price`, obviously a mistake, he meant columns.

Comment: His sample contains 6 rows. But I'm not sure. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @Yusufsn he also specified that `There are 1 million+ entries`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv

f_file = open ('myfile.csv')
csv_f_file = csv.reader(p_supermarket_file)

account_id = []
for row in csv_f_file:
    account_id.append(row[4])

account_id = set(account_id)
account_id_list = list(account_id)
for id in account_id_list:
    for row in csv_f_file:
        if row[3] == id:
            total_amount = row[4] * row[5]
#make a dictionary to store amount and its corresponding is in it.
```

I have not tested it but it i from what i understood.

Answer (score -1):

Give a try to Pandas. Use groupby method with lamda.
If your CSV file have features row wise take the transpose and then use groupby method.

Only refer pandas official documentation sites.

Comment: I would do pandas but this is a homework assignment and it says in the instructions that we are not allowed to. Thank you though!